# Troubleshooting iOS Push Notifications (Node/Cordova)

Tags: ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications

We're trying to send push notifications to users using the `node-apn` module on the backend and the `phonegap-plugin-push` module on the client. On our development server and build this seemed to be working, but in our production app on the App Store no push notifications seem to be received. The client is registering for push notifications, has the correct notification permission, and passes its device token back to the server. When I try to send a push to that device from our server with debugging turned on, I get:

```
apn Initialising connection +0ms
apn Loading Credentials +2ms
apn 1 left to send +3ms
info sending apns Fri Oct 02 2015 17:08:12 GMT+0000 (UTC) { deviceType: 'ios',
info sending apns  deviceToken: '<token>' } { title: 'test title',
info sending apns  message: undefined,
info sending apns  route: undefined,
info sending apns  params: { id: undefined } }
apn Connection established +144ms
apn Socket drained +103ms 0
apn 0 left to send +1ms
apn 0 left to send +0ms
```

Those undefined properties are ones not required to send that I didn't fill in — adding them does not make a difference here. The APN connection isn't reporting any errors (there was an earlier error around the certificate not including a particular CA, but I fixed that), but no message is ever received on the device. The only difference between dev and production here should be the certificates/profiles, and I believe those are configured correctly.

Is there any other way to troubleshoot an issue like this? Is there any way through Apple's developer tools to confirm that device tokens are valid (other than trying to send to them, which it is trying to), or to send test messages other than directly through our backend? I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this since I'm not actually seeing any errors. Please let me know if there are other details I can provide that would be helpful here.